# SPH : Kernel Gradient Correction

Tags: vector-analysis, density-function, simulation

I'm struggling to understand the kernel gradient correction to restore consistency of the SPH methods on free surface or boundary. Where does the definition of M come from?

\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        \nabla W_{ij}' & = L_i \nabla W_{ij}\\
        L_i & = M_i^{-1}\\
        M_i & = \sum_{j\in neigh(i)}\frac{m_j}{\rho_j}\nabla W \otimes (r_i-r_j)
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Does anyone has a reference or somethings where is has been described

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey I found the solutions.
The major problem for the consistency is that on the boundary, the density is no more symmetric around a particle and so the gradient computation is biased.\
To have a good gradient computation we need :
\begin{equation}
    \sum_{j\in neigh(i)}^N\frac{m_j}{\rho_j}(x_j-x_i)\otimes \nabla W_j(x_i) = \textbf{I} \qquad \forall i\in\text{Particles}
\end{equation}
To ensure that even on the boundary let's define $W_{ij}' = L_i \nabla W_{ij}$. It gives
\begin{equation}
    \sum_{j\in neigh(i)}^N\frac{m_j}{\rho_j}(x_j-x_i)\otimes L_i \nabla W_j(x_i) = \textbf{I} \qquad \forall i\in\text{Particles}\label{kgc:cdt1}
\end{equation}
Now if we take $L_i = \left(\sum_{j\in neigh(i)}^N\frac{m_j}{\rho_j}\nabla W_j(x_i)\otimes(x_j-x_i)\right)^{-1}$ we have that this condition holds for every particles even them on the borders.